# Expression Engine PHP & Embed & entry_id_from

Tags: php, embeds, php-errors, template-scripting, querystring

i have the following Line:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders"  entry_id_from="{embed:LAST_ID}" sort="desc" dynamic="no"}
```

LAST_ID file :

```
<?
include '!mysql.php';
$last_id = @mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT comanda_id_end FROM output_comenzi ORDER BY id DESC'),0);
if(!$last_id) $last_id = 0;
echo $last_id;
?>
```

How can I make that the LAST_ID file to get PARSED, take the value and insert it into entry_id_from

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your embed syntax is incorrect. `{embed:LAST_ID}` assumes that the template you're running has been embedded from within another template, and that the parent template's embed code had a parameter named `LAST_ID`, which has now been passed tot he template you're in.

What I think you are wanting to do it use the value of an embedded template in your `channel:entries` tag, which you can't do, because [embeds run at the very end of the template engine](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html), after all module tags have been run.

But you don't need an embed here, just PHP enabled in your template, set to "Input". Then, change your Channel Entries code to:

```
entry_id_from="<?php echo $last_id ; ?>"
```

Also, if the `output_comenzi` table is located in the same database as your EE tables, you can simplify your query using EE's database class.

```
$query = ee()->db->query('SELECT comanda_id_end FROM output_comenzi ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
$last_id = ($query->num_rows() == 1) ? $query->row('comanda_id_end') : 0;
```

Comment: Hei Derek, the this is that The file with the entry_id_from="$last_id" must be set on output as i am getting some variables into an array and writing them into a file. How Can I pas $last_id into  entry_id_from value?

Comment: Input vs Output when enabled PHP in a template has only to do with whether the PHP blocks are processed before or after EE module/plugin tags are processed.

Comment: Well, how can I pass the Variable into  entry_id_from="here" in Php se on output, is there any way? Other than that is there any PHP syntax to replace Exp Channel Entries ? Is it possible to use with Low variables or any other third plugin ?

Comment: You could write a simple plugin that has your `last_id` value as a variable, and wrap that plugin around your Channel Entries tag, with `parse="inward"` on it.